# Is there a way of converting a T to a IEnumerable<T> without using Add or AddRange

Tags: c#, asp.net, ienumerable

I have a a list of nodes:

```
IEnumerable<Node> list
```

I also have a singlular item

```
Node item
```

Is it possible to directly replace list with item without a List.Add or List.AddRange?

```
list = item // do something here to convert/cast
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
IEnumerable<Node> list = new[] { item };
```

A single element array?

Equivalent to:

```
IEnumerable<Node> list = new Node[] { item };
```

Answer (score 3):

Lots of ways, another perhaps is the extension

```
public static IEnumerable<T> ToEnumerable<T>(this T source)
{
    yield return source;
}
```

So you could do

```
IEnumerable<Node> aSequenceOfOne = item.ToEnumerable();
```

---

Although in practice, [the array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18272358/659190) has always seemed pragmatic, despite the allocation.

Comment: Considering that your response will `new` an hidden class for the `IEnumerable<Node>`, it's like the pot calling the kettle black :-)

Comment: @xanatos, I agree, I suspect the allocation of the array is somewhat simpler behind the scenes.